# CSS starts with search and then class

Tags: css

I need to set the background color of a `th` that is dynamically generated and has a patterned id, and when clicked on has the class active. I understand how to find the `th` where the id begins with a pattern. In my case it's the following:

```
th[id^='tableHeaderPartialID'] {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

That will set the background color to all th's that match the search, but I need to have a specific class with it also. I tried:

```
th[id^='tableHeaderPartialID'] .active
```

which didn't work. How do I have a search and a class in the same call?

Answer (score 2):

```
th[id^='tableHeaderPartialID'].active
```

No space.  Space looks for `.active` nested within your `th`.  You want the `th` to have the class so there's no space.